# Неправильно выводит информациию клиент?

Tags: java

Проблема заключается в том что текст у клиента выводиться не правильно. 
 Текст у клиента должен выводиться так, каждое число с новой строки 
 Помогите пожалуйста

```
Как выводиться:
0
12345 //вот этого не должно быть 
6
7
8
9
10
1112   //вот этого не должно быть 
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20212223242526272829303132 //вот этого не должно быть 
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
424344  //вот этого не должно быть 
45
46
47
48
4950
51
52535455 //вот этого не должно быть 
56
57
58
59
60616263  // вот этого не должно быть 
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
777879  //вот этого не должно быть 
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
888990 //вот этого не должно быть 
91
9293  //вот этого не должно быть 
94
95
96
97
98
99





import java.io.*;
    import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Client side");

        Socket fromserver = null;

        fromserver = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        InputStream in = fromserver.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = fromserver.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader inu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String fuser;
        int fserver;


        while ((fuser = inu.readLine()) != null) {


            out.write(fuser.getBytes());
            out.flush();


            byte buf[] = new byte[64 * 1024];

            while ((fserver = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                String input = new String(buf, 0, fserver);
                System.out.println(input);
                if (input.equals("stop")) break;

            }


            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) break;
            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        inu.close();
        fromserver.close();
    }
}



import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    public static String output = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Server side");
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        ServerSocket servers = null;
        Socket fromclient = null;

        // create server socket
        try {
            servers = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't listen to port 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try {
            System.out.print("Waiting for a client...");
            fromclient = servers.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't accept");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        in = fromclient.getInputStream();
        out = fromclient.getOutputStream();


        System.out.println("Wait for messages");

        while (true) {
            byte buf[] = new byte[64*1024];
            int r = in.read(buf);
            String  input = new String(buf, 0, r);

            System.out.println(input);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                out.write(Integer.toString(i).getBytes());
                out.flush();
            }
            out.write("stop".getBytes());
            out.flush();

            if(input.equals("exit")) break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        fromclient.close();
        servers.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое предположение - у тебя в потоке данных с сервера нет переводов строк (ньюлайнов), т.к. ты пишель в выходной поток только строковые представления чисел подряд (хотя в отладочном выводе печатаешь каждое с новой строки ,благодаря суффиксу ln в println):

```
System.out.println(i);
out.write(Integer.toString(i).getBytes());
```

Далее, на клиенте у тебя порциями считываются данные с сервера и выводятся опять же через println:

```
String input = new String(buf, 0, fserver);
System.out.println(input);
```

И тут лотерея - если за время передачи одного числа сервером клиент успеет его принять и напечатать с переводом строки - то все хорошо, если задержка в канале ,и приходит порция символов подряд - то напечатается она в одну строку, а потом перевод на новую строку за счет ln. Потому что переводов строк нет в потоке передачи.

Выход: добавить в выходной поток с сервера переводы строк, а на клиенте печатать принятое не по println, а по print.

Comment: Идея очень интересная, но есть 1 проблема. 
Пример:
Клиент отправляет Серверу: Все хорошо  отправил stop
Сервер отправил данные : Все хорошо  принял stop
Клиент отправляет Серверу: Все хорошо отправил stop
Сервер отправил данные : Все хорошо принял stop
Клиент отправляет Серверу: Все хорошо отправил stop
Сервер отправил данные : Все плохо не принял stop

Что делать тогда ?

Comment: Грубо говоря он не выходит из этого цикла у клиента 

while ((fserver = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                String input = new String(buf, 0, fserver);
                System.out.print(input);
                if (input.equals("stop")) break;

            }